# Postgres stopped connection on 127.0.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I know this subject has been discussed, but none of the answers have helped me.  Sorry, for starting a new topic on it...and thank you to anyone who helps.

I have been developing on my local machine everyday...its NOT a new set up, but abruptly the server wont connect...and not sure why.

My original install of postgres was via homebrew.  Im using pg gem version 0.15.1, ruby 2.0, rails 3.2.13, postgres 9.2.4.

## $bundle exec rails s

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting

/Users/Hank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails329/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `initialize': could not connect to server: Connection refused (PG::Error)

Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
    could not connect to server: Connection refused

    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
    could not connect to server: Connection refused

    Is the server running on host "localhost" (fe80::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

## $brew info postgres

```
  postgresql: stable 9.2.4
```

Usually when I get any server errors I can force stop or restart and then restart my machine and all is well.  this time, I have tried a slew of pg_ctl commands, restarts, rebuild permissions and run disc utility, gem pristine pg, uninstall pg, reinstall pg, brew update postgres, would have deleted the .pid file but there isnt one currently created.

## $which postgres

```
  /usr/local/bin/postgres
```

## $which psql

```
 /usr/local/bin/psql
```

## $ps aux | grep postgres

```
 returns: 1976   0.0  0.0  2430992   1584 s000  R+    8:54PM   0:00.01 grep postgres
```

Comment: The error message and the `ps` output indicate that PostgreSQL isn't running. Have you tried `pg_ctl start`? If you have, what did it say?

Comment: It returns...
pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset
Try "pg_ctl --help" for more information.

Comment: And pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/data start returns - server starting -
postgres cannot access the server configuration file "/Library/PostgreSQL/data/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory

Comment: Do you have a `postgres.conf` file anywhere?

Comment: I have a postgresql.conf.  I was gonna post it but its fairly long and I havent altered it.

Comment: I think I just realized that these troubles are somehow related to the postgres.app.  I opened the app...which started pg.  Then tried starting my rails server and got a new error that the database does not exist.  I re-initialzed postgres earlier today...not realizing I dumped all my databases.  crap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had installed the new postgres.app, which basically takes control of the pg environment.  I forgot all about it, and the app for some reason stopped auto starting the server when my computer started up.  So, having forgot about the app...and it not auto loading...I couldnt figure out why I had no control over my pg server and why I could not get it to start.

PS - the postgres.app is great!  As long as you dont forget your using it...